# Vim automatically load all tag files

Tags: vim, ctags

I would like to automatically load all (c)tag file from a specific directory on startup of VIM. Currently I add them by hand:

```
set tags+=~/.tags/tag1
set tags+=~/.tags/tag2
set tags+=~/.tags/tag3
```

I would like to load all files via a wildcard and I tried something like this:

```
set tags+=~/.tags/*
```

which unfortunately doesn't work. Any ideas how I get this to work?

Best wishes, Peter

Comment: It looks like vim uses the wildcard for directory names not for tag names so `set tags+=~/.tags/*/tags` would probably work where each tags file is in its own directory. I'm not sure why you need more than one tags file though. Read `:help 'tags'`

Comment: @FDinoff Having more than one tag file is quite useful actually. For instance, I have one for the C++ standard library, one for boost, one for ITK, one OTB, one fro GDAL, etc. However, I explicitly load them, one by one as I seldom want use all of them simultaneously.

Comment: @LucHermitte I guess Im curious why you would need more than one in the same directory. I assume you have the tags file with the source instead of in one directory?

Comment: @FDinoff. Because libraries are installed and scattered in various places like `/usr/include/c++/{gcc-version}`, `/usr/include/boost`, `$HOME/local/libfoo/include` (the only place where I'd be permitted to generate a tag file), `/opt/libbar/include` and I'd rather keep all their respective tag files in a same directory. It's easier for me to remember where to search.

Comment: For each of my own projects a have a tag file in the corresponding directory and for example libraries like boost and others I have the file in my home directory. Currently I load each file separately by name, but since I sync my .vimrc over different machine I would like to have a generic solution. I was just curious that for such a simple problem, there doesn't seem to be a simple solution. I guess I will go for @FDinoff 's suggestion and place each file in its own directory.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to play with `glob()` I guess.

Something like (untested):

```
exe 'set tags+='.substitute(glob('~/.tags'), "\n", ',', 'g')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple tag files in your .vimrc in the following manner by separating the list of tags files with a space, but you need to backslash your space.

example follows with 2.  I do this to bring in tag files from my libraries.

```
set tags=./TAGS\ /path/to/your/other/TAGS
```

While in vi, you can type the following while in command mode;

```
:set tags=./TAGS\ /path/to/your/other/TAGS
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t see how this differs from the approach in the Question: the goal is to not have to manually add multiple tag files (you change the format of doing so, but don’t address that the OP doesnt want to at all).

Comment: Clearly the above can easily be added to ones .vimrc file.  I was just providing the syntax to show how to load multiple tag files.  They are separated by a space and require a backslash before the space.  I apologize if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (in .vimrc):

```
for tagfile in split(globpath('$PWD/.tags/', '*'), '\n')
    let &tags .=',' . tagfile
endfor
```

I use `$PWD` because I always generate my tag files from the top of the project (and placed in `.tags` dir) and launch vim from the top (so `$PWD` works in my case) - but you can substitute for any hardcoded directory.